# Do I need to set authority on newly minted token after I transfer it?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, transfer, authority

I have a program to mint tokens on behalf of users (with user-provided metadata for the tokens) and after the minting is done, I transfer the token to the user address.

Now, my question is - do I need to [Set Authority](https://yihau.github.io/solana-web3-demo/advanced/token/set-authority.html) on the token after it's been transferred?

I'm asking because I want to prevent even myself from having access to the user's token after transfer.

Here's [an example token](https://solscan.io/token/3yxNauGKuwq441Kp5v82Pp4CoHbx7tt8yufpAM145cFb?cluster=devnet) I've minted for a test user. I guess my primary reason for raising this question is the fact that the `Update Authority` address in Solscan, even after the transfer, is still the account from which the token was minted.

Comment: this can't really be answered accurately without the code that's doing the mint and transfer steps

Answer (score 1):

yes if u want that nobody can update the metadata but only the user to whom u r transferring the NFT then u need to transfer the update authority also to the end user.
So when u transfer the NFT call this instruction also createUpdateMetadataAccountV2Instruction
and change the new_update_authority to the end user's publickey.
This will transfer the update authority to the end user and reflect the same in the metadata and solscan

Comment: So, after I mint and transfer, the NFT is owned by the user, but not the NFT's Metadata token? And my wallet is still the authority that can update the NFT's metadata?

Also, I cannot find `createUpdateMetadataAccountV2Instruction` in `@solana/spl-token` npm library.

Comment: after u transfer the update authority of the NFT only the new user's wallet can update the metadata so essentially he will be the one owning the metadata too..if u try to update the metadata from your wallet it will give an error that the signer is not the authority.. and u can find the instruction in this link https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html. U need to import from @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata